Can someone help identify this component value?
Can someone help identify this component value?
It looks like 420L 0042.
The spacing is 7.5 mm on the legs.


It appears to be a Metal Oxide Varistor (MOV) not a capacitor.
They absorb voltage spikes and are often connected to the power lines.
This specific one seems to be from Littlefuse LA Varistor Series, Datasheet.


I guess that it's one of the V420L line, if you could measure the diameter, we could be sure.

Altough the markings in the datasheet do not seem to fit perfectly, i would argue that it's most likely a older version from LittleFuse or a clone from a different manufacture with similar specs.

Hi, thanks very much for your help, the diameter is 10mm

Upvoted. @Gandalf, if this is a clear and correct answer to your question then please consider accepting it as the answer, rather than leave it open. Thanks.

"Altough the markings in the datasheet do not seem to fit perfectly," It doesn't fit at all. Maybe what's on the picture is a pre-RoHS part from year 2000, week 42. RoHS went live in 2006.

@Lundin I meant more the style of marking with multiline and letters but without points or other symbols, bad wording on my side. I would agree on your date guess, good point with RoHs!
